# Where to put constants in a class: standards and best practice

Tags: java, coding-style, constants, standards, conventions

While coding some custom stream reader for a script result where quite a lot of constants were present in the class (mainly for expected tags and keywords), I was wondering if there was any kind of standards, conventions or best practice for where to put constants (read here `static final` fields) inside a class?

More specifically, is it considered best to put every constant in the top of the class, or to group them up in the area of the class where they are useful, and group the commons at the top?

By putting everything in the top, it seems to me that this might be easier to find everything you're looking for at the same place, but it can get overwhelming if this area is getting bigger:

```
public class Test {
    // Constants.
    private static final String CLASSNAME = Test.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String COMMON = " = ";
    private static final String CONSTRUCTOR = "#constructor";
    private static final String METHOD_1 = "#method1";
    private static final String METHOD_2 = "#method2";

    public Test(String message) {
        System.out.println(CLASSNAME + CONSTRUCTOR + COMMON + message);
        method1(message);
        method2(message);
    }

    private void method1(String message) {
        System.out.println(CLASSNAME + METHOD_1 + COMMON + message);
    }

    private void method2(String message) {
        System.out.println(CLASSNAME + METHOD_2 + COMMON + message);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

By grouping them up, it makes more sense to the constants that are only used in specific areas of the class, but it may break the nice *symmetrical* effect grouping by types adds to a class, and might make it look *messy*:

```
public class Test {
    // Common constants.
    private static final String CLASSNAME = Test.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String COMMON = " = ";

    // Constructor constants.
    private static final String CONSTRUCTOR = "#constructor";

    public Test(String message) {
        System.out.println(CLASSNAME + CONSTRUCTOR + COMMON + message);
        method1(message);
        method2(message);
    }

    // Constant proper to method1(...).
    private static final String METHOD_1 = "#method1";

    private void method1(String message) {
        System.out.println(CLASSNAME + METHOD_1 + COMMON + message);
    }

    // Constant proper to method2(...).
    private static final String METHOD_2 = "#method2";

    private void method2(String message) {
        System.out.println(CLASSNAME + METHOD_2 + COMMON + message);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Test#constructor = Hello world!
Test#method1 = Hello world!
Test#method2 = Hello world!
```

I know this might be the subjective kind of question, but I'm mainly interested in finding out if there is any (un)official document stating this, or which of the above scenarios is considered best practice and more appealing to work with for the average programmer.

*Take note that the Javadoc was discarded to lighten up the above example code.*

Comment: Do you really intend to write to System.out every method invocation? Why do you define these strings as constants? They're used only once, and using constants this make the code less readable than using the literal Strings directly.

Comment: @JBNizet This simple code is only an example for the sake of the question, and I chose `String` but that could have been any type. Of course defining _use once_ fields is a bit too much, but try extrapolate the constants defined above as being used multiple times in the class (or method) in a real world use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a standard set of conventions on Oracle's site. There's a [reference to how to layout the source code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html#1852) that places static variables ahead of instance variables, but there's nothing particular about constants.

Oracle's style guide has not been updated since 1999,and has a warning on it that the information may no longer be valid. [Google has a more up-to-date style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s3.4.2-class-member-ordering), it says:

> 3.4.2 Class member ordering
>
> The ordering of the members of a class can have a great effect on
>   learnability, but there is no single correct recipe for how to do it.
>   Different classes may order their members differently.
>
> What is important is that each class order its members in some logical
>   order, which its maintainer could explain if asked. For example, new
>   methods are not just habitually added to the end of the class, as that
>   would yield "chronological by date added" ordering, which is not a
>   logical ordering.

Common practice is to put constants at the top ahead of everything else, but there's no absolute mandate. If you have a lot of constants and need to organize them, grouping them in enums would be one alternative.

Comment: Interesting references, and enums are a good alternative suggestion for classes heavily loaded by constants. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically, constants go at the top, and are named in upper case. As @AlexisLeclerc says in the comments, you should only use constants when they are used in more than once place, otherwise you're just making the code harder to read. However, this is idiomatic, not standard.

If you're grouping things in your class as described, it may indicate that you should actually have two or more classes.